# How to insert into a repeatedptrfiled just like vector.insert(iterator)

Tags: protocol-buffers

std::vector has a function to insert, which is

```
iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, const _Ty& _Val) { // insert _Val at _Where
        return emplace(_Where, _Val);
    }
```

is there any similar interface in repeatedptrfiled or some other way to insert into a repeatedptrfield by iterator but not index.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field), there is nothing that allows you to set a value using an iterator. The closest thing is `Set(int index, const Element& value)` which is rather unfortunate. If you want to use a range based for loop but need Python-like element enumeration, consider using `enumerate` from [CPPItertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Hy, the repeated field from protobuf is a std::vector and you can use the insert from it. Not very elegantly but it should work.

Comment: This isn't true? Can you please point to evidence supporting this answer.